# Get the ip address using the mac address on a networked device

Tags: networking, coldfusion, network-programming

If I know the mac address of a device on a local network, and I know part of the ip address (192.168.112.???), can I find the last 3 numbers using any type of web technology? 
 The device is an ip phone on a vpn with the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work on a windows environment. Using CFEXECUTE run a batchfile containing this the command:

```
C:\>arp -g
```

The CF code would look something like:

```
<cfexecute name="arp.bat" variable="arpAddresses"/>
```

You might also have to experiment with adding an enterface to that command if you have multiple IPs registered on the card. The results will look like this.

```
Interface: 10.0.0.21 --- 0xc
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.0.0.4              dc-0e-a1-34-c6-5e     dynamic
  10.0.0.6              00-26-2d-7d-b6-ae     dynamic
  10.0.0.8              8c-89-a5-54-4b-e8     dynamic
  10.0.0.9              84-8f-69-aa-10-2d     dynamic
  10.0.0.11             00-15-5d-00-32-03     dynamic
  10.0.0.14             00-8c-fa-3f-56-8e     dynamic
  10.0.0.15             00-15-5d-00-32-12     dynamic
  10.0.0.22             78-ac-c0-a4-fd-17     dynamic
...
```

They are separated by spaces belive with the MAC address always occuring at line 63? You'll have to experiment with that. Using this data you should be able to build a query or structure or array or whatever and tease out which IP belongs to which IP.

I would add that there are some java libraries that allow access to the stack and would likely get you there as well.

Comment: This answer assumes the CF server has recently interacted with the other server in order for the mac/ip to be cached in arp but the op didn't necessarily state that. That's why I suggested pinging each ip in the ip range to ensure recent contact.

Comment: @BradWood - that's a good catch. I didn't go quite that far since he said that "he knew the mac address" - I assumed he had that covered I guess. Good Call.

Answer (score 2):

If both devices are on the same local network, you could try iterating over each IP in the last octet (1-254) and pinging, and then parsing the output of your OS's **ARP** command to look at the MAC addresses.

http://compnetworking.about.com/od/tcpip/f/convertmacipadd.htm

Disclaimer, I've never tried this so YMMV

Comment: Sounds like he knows the MAC already, so couldn't he just parse the `arp` output? (I have not tried it either). Edit: Not sure how long it stays in cache though.

Comment: Leigh, that's exactly what I was suggesting. Parse the  arp output to find the mac address, then find the ip on the same line.  Basically what Mark said, but he just explained it a bit more thoroughly.  If they ping each ip in the octect like I suggested, they should all be in cache, though there may be a limit to the cache size.

Comment: No, your explanation was fine. It was my comment that was a little vague. I had not fully thought through caching. I realized afterward, the IP won't necessarily be in cache, and that is why you cannot just read the `arp` results. You must ping first.